# SAS Input Data using Columns

Tags: sas

Consider the following SAS code:

```
***COLUMN INPUT; 
DATA COL1; 
 INPUT X 1-2 
 Y 3 
 A $ 4-10 
 Z 11; 
DATALINES; 
 12HELLO 3 
4 5GOODBYE6 
; 
PROC PRINT DATA=COL1; 
 TITLE 'COLUMN INPUT'; 
RUN;
```

In the  `INPUT`  statement, does the  `X 1-2`  indicate that the variable X begins on column 1 and ends on column 2? Wouldn't the input  `12HELLO 3`   put 12 in variable X, H in variable Y, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct in your interpretation of the input statement.  However, you are forgetting about the initial space in the datalines.  X is `| 1|` not `|12|`.  Y is `2` and `HELLO 3` is in A (though I suspect it should be two spaces, so `|HELLO  |` is in A and 3 goes into Z.  (using | to indicate where spaces are so they don't get stripped).